# LuaJIT - lint option

Tags: lua, bytecode, luajit

I have been looking at the `lint` kind of utils for `Lua`, and read about `LuaInspect`, `LuaLint` and `MetaLlint`. I am using `LuaJIT-2.0.2`, and my needs are quite simple, I need to be able to only inspect accesses of the sort of `MODNAME:function()`. Other than `MetaLint` (which needs `MetaLua` runtime), the rest seem to be doing bytecode dump and parse, check for global accesses.

So, if I want to implement a simple utility for my source, on similar lines, I should be looking for `GGET` and `TGETS` opcodes in the output of `luajit -b -l source.lua`, e.g:

```
0019    GGET     4   1      ; "MODNAME"
0020    TGETS    4   4   8  ; "function"
```

Are there better alternatives/approaches?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it you want to do exactly? Maybe you could do something with the Lua debug library, for instance debug.sethook (http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-debug.sethook).

Comment: I want to do *static-checks* on the code to ensure only known module/functions [that I am adding] are invoked. This will be done just after `luaL_loadfile`. Debug hooks, AFAIK, are runtime!

Comment: OK, then either you inspect the bytecode like you showed or you use one of the various Lua parsers available on your code to detect this.

Comment: @catwell do you mean Lua source parsers, or the bytecode list parsers?

Comment: I mean source parsers. You could find that from an AST or some intermediate representation.